# Is it possible for an Facebook app with messenger chat bot functionality (webhook and messenger), to receive messages sent to my user profile?

Tags: facebook, messenger, facebook-webhooks

I have a Facebook user profile that is admin of a company page.
I'm developing an app with "messenger chat bot" functionality. It is receiving all messenger messages sent to the company page.
I would like this app to also process all messenger messages sent to my user profile page.
Is this possible?

Comment: No it is not possible.

Comment: Hi WizKid. Thank you for your help. So, what you're saying is that an User Profile Page cannot have a chatbot in their Messenger?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Chatbots are for communication between a page and a user only.